# How can I change font color of the rows of columngroup in ssrs-2010 matrix

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I have a such matrix [image]
[image]

I want to change the font color of the dates(in rows of columngroup) are seen in the picture along with the status value is plan that depends on whether the difference of plan and actual dates that has been referred as Delay/Early By. 
For doing this at first i wrote in color expression,

`=IIf(Fields!Status.Value="Delay/Early By" & CInt(Fields!CompleteDate.Value)<0,"Red","Green")`

But it shows only the rows along with Delay/Early By green.
Then I add a datafield name diff to store the date differences and wrote in color expression

`=IIf(Fields!Status.Value=" Plan" & Fields!diff.Value<0,"Red","Green")`

it also didn't work. It shows all the rows green.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'AND' instead of '&' in ur expression. It may resolve ur issue.

Let me know if you are still facing the problem.

Comment: As far I know there is no problem with '&'. I used it successfully before. Yet tried your solution and it didn't work.

Comment: In that case somehow your 1st condition (Fields!Status.Value=" Plan") in the iif block is always failing and printing "Green".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Sarat is correct.  You are using the concatenation operator '&' when you should be using the comparison operator 'AND'.